# WPF How to resize Grid depending on the content inside?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I currently have a reusable overlay, that displays a Button and it's content.

```xml
<Border Visibility="{Binding Content, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
    <Border.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.8" />
    </Border.Background>
    
    <Grid Height="450" Width="450">
        <Border Background="NavajoWhite"
                CornerRadius="3" 
                BorderBrush="Black" 
                BorderThickness="2">
            <Grid Margin="10">
                    
                <!-- Display Content of selected ViewModel -->
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}"/>
                    
                <!-- Close button -->
                <Button Content="X" 
                        FontSize="14" 
                        Width="45" 
                        Height="45" 
                        Command="{Binding Close}" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

**Problem**

I have some forms that fit in perfectly to the above XAML

[image]

And some forms don't fit

[image]

**Question**

As the height and width are currently set to hard coded values `Height: 450  Width: 450` within the XAML, is there a way to auto adjust the grid's height and width depending on it's content inside the Grid? Not to be too small for the content not to be visible and not too large to avoid too much whitespace.

Comment: MinWidth, MinHeight at 450 and let the grid expands itself, dont set a Width and Height if you autosize.

Comment: @DrkDeveloper I have tried both 1. Remove height and width 2. Set the MinHeight and MinWidth. They both just expand to full width.

Comment: VerticalAlignment, the default value is "Stretch" and make the grid be greedy

Comment: @DrkDeveloper Got it - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have a constraint at a higher level (UserControl, Window layout), then split the nested Grid into two lines.
At the bottom line (intended for Buttons), set the autosize.
For the buttons themselves, set the Margin, Padding and their position (aligment).
Perhaps it will be convenient for a row with buttons to first add some kind of general container (StackPanel, UniformGrid, etc.) and add buttons to it.

It is also important: in the layout at a higher level without limiting the maximum size of the main Border to give it some kind of aligment other than «Stretch».
Setting «Stretch » will expand main Border to the maximum possible size.

```
<Border Background="#80FFFFFF" 
    Visibility="{Binding Content, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
    <!--<Border.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
    </Border.Background>-->

    <!--<Grid Height="450" Width="450">-->
    <Border Background="NavajoWhite" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"
                MinHeight="450" MinWidth="450">
        <Grid Margin="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!--Display Content of selected ViewModel-->
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}" />

            <!--Close button-->
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Margin="5" Padding="15 5"
                        Content="Create" FontSize="14" Command="{Binding Close}"/>
                <Button Margin="5" Padding="15 5"
                        Content="X" FontSize="14" Command="{Binding Close}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <!--</Grid>-->
</Border>
```